# finding substring within a list in Python

Tags: python, substring

I have a list like:

```
a = ['aaa/aa/aa/a001', 'aaa/aa/aa/a002', 'aaa/aa/aa/a003']
```

I want to retrieve the number part.  How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, did the answers help?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

a = ['aaa/aa/aa/a001','aaa/aa/aa/a002','aaa/aa/aa/a003']

for elem in a:
    print (re.sub(r"[^0-9]","",elem))
```

Output:

```
001
002
003
```

Or, with list comprehension:

```
numbers = [re.sub(r"[^0-9]","",x) for x in a]

print (numbers)
```

Output:

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try regex:

```
import re
a = ['aaa/aa/aa/a001','aaa/aa/aa/a002','aaa/aa/aa/a003']
print([re.sub('[^\d+]', '', i) for i in a])
```

Output:

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

Or you could try using `str.join`:

```
print([''.join(x for x in i if x.isdigit()) for i in a])
```

Output:

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension with `re.sub`:

```py
a = ['aaa/aa/aa/a001','aaa/aa/aa/a002','aaa/aa/aa/a003']
out = [re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+)$', r'\1', x) for x in a]
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

The strategy here is to match and capture the digits at the end of each string in the list.  Note that this approach is robust even if digits might also appear earlier in the string.

Comment: If I have a = ['aaa/aa/aa/Lv2a001','aaa/aa/aa/Lv2a002','aaa/aa/aa/Lv2a003'], Is it possible to get ['001', '002', '003'] ?

Comment: @이원석 My answer also should work for this input.  [Check the demo](https://rextester.com/GXNJN71251).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally, I have a one further question. Then if i want to extract the earlier number from 'aaa/aa/aa/L2a001.he5' what should I change ?

Comment: @이원석 Use the regex pattern `^.*?(\d+)\D+\d+$` and then also access the first capture group `\1` as the replacement.

Comment: I'd drop all the ancestor nodes, via `value.split("/")[-1]` first, before using your regex.  That avoids numerical patterns higher up impacting what seems to concern only the leaves.